# Covariant derivative of a tensor

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have one question. I'm new in tensor calculus, so question may seem like stupid. Covariant derivative of a tensor $T^\alpha$:
$$\nabla_\beta T^\alpha=\frac{\partial T^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}+\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\mu}T^\mu$$
But if I have a tensor as a matrix (lets say tensor with diagonal values -1;1;1;1, other equal to zero) how can I understand what is $T^\mu$? In this case I don't have any coordinates for a matrix like column and row number. Please, if It won't be hard, provide an example for a better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what the other questions state, if you're trying to work out what a tensor derivative shoudl look like, consider a tensor made of vectors:

$$T^{ab} = v^{a}v^{b}$$

Then, since covariant derivatives obey the Liebniz rule

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{c}T^{ab} &= \nabla_{c}\left(v^{a}v^{b}\right)\\
&= v^{b}\nabla_{c}v^{a} + v^{a}\nabla_{c}v^{b}\\
&= v^{b}\partial_{c}v^{a} + v^{b}\Gamma_{cd}{}^{a}v^{d} + v^{a}\partial_{c}v^{b} + v^{a}\Gamma_{cd}{}^{b}v^{d}\\
&= \partial_{c}T^{ab} + \Gamma_{cd}{}^{a}T^{bd} +\Gamma_{cd}{}^{b}T^{ad}
\end{align}$$

And there you go, there's your rule for the derivative of rank-2 tensors with two "up" indices.  If you have "down"  indices, they follow the one-form rule (by a similar pseudo-proof), and then you're done.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. But, please, can you explain what do you mean by "one-form rule"? Just change $$\nabla_\beta T^\alpha=\frac{\partial T^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}+\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\mu}T^\mu$$ on$$\nabla_\beta T_\alpha=\frac{\partial T_\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}-\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}T_\mu$$

Comment: @AlexSok Consider the covariant derivative of the scalar $T_\alpha T^\alpha$ and use the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Or I just can use uppering of the index ?$T^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: @AlexSok : you can pull out factors of $g$ if you want, but you'll end up with factors like $g_{ab}\Gamma_{cd}{}^{b}$, which you can show will end up being the same thing as just using that other rule for one-forms.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Pulling out the metric is only possible for metric/Levi-Civita connections, while using the Leibniz rule is more general. So it might be a good exercise in GR, but in general it's better not to use it if not required.

Comment: @NDewolf I was more saying (for metrics without null eigenvalues) you can always rewrite $\nabla_{a}\omega_{b}$ as $\nabla_{a}\left(g_{bc}\omega^{c}\right)$ and then turn all of the cranks.  but yes, I agree with you.